# Logout from Navigation Drawer

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, logout

I would like to create a logout alert dialog from my applications navigation drawer. All the other items in the nav drawer are fragments and I would like for this item to just show an alert dialog

[Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnMOl.jpg)

I previously had a button in my MainActivity that used an on click listener and firebase.getInstance.signOut() to take the user back to the login activity:

Previous button on click listener

```
 //on click listener for logout
    /*btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });*/
```

After some redesign I created a navigation drawer that utilizes fragments and i would like when the user selects logout to be prompted with an alert dialog asking are they sure , then for the button to act just how my previous one did and send the user back to the login activity.

I dont see the need of creating another fragment to logout but, correct me if I'm wrong.

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.
    OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,MainFragment.onFragmentBtnSelected{


public TextView verifyMsg;
public Button btnLogout, verifyEmailBtn;
FirebaseAuth fauth;
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
public NavigationView navigationView;
AlertDialog.Builder reset_alert;
LayoutInflater inflater;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //xml map to java
    //btnLogout = findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailMsg);
    verifyEmailBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnVerifyEmail);
    fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    reset_alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    inflater =this.getLayoutInflater();

    //new stuff
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new
            ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            toolbar, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    //fragment manager - creates instance of a fragment
    //load default fragment
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_fragment,new MainFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    //if the user email is not verified still show verify msg
    if(!fauth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){
        verifyEmailBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    //on click listener for verify email button
    verifyEmailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //send verification email
            fauth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Verification Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    verifyEmailBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
//able to select the items in nav drawer
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    //auto close drawer
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    //Fragment fragment;
    int mId = item.getItemId();
    }
    if (mId == R.id.homeItem){
        //load default fragment
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment,new MainFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    if (mId == R.id.profileSettings){
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment,new ProfileFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    if (mId == R.id.logoutItem){

    }


    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBtnSelected() {
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment,new ProfileFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
} }
```

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private onFragmentBtnSelected listener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
   Button clickme = view.findViewById(R.id.clickHF);
   clickme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           listener.onBtnSelected();
       }
   });
   return view;
}
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof onFragmentBtnSelected ){
        listener =(onFragmentBtnSelected) context;
    }
    else {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement listiner");
    }
}
public interface onFragmentBtnSelected{
    public void onBtnSelected();
}
```

}

nav_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:title="General">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/homeItem"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
            android:title="@string/Home" />

    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="Account Settings">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profileSettings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
            android:title="Profile" />

    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="App Features">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/logoutItem"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_power_settings_new_24"
            android:title="@string/logout" />
    </menu>
</item></menu>
```

Any help would be greatly appreatiated , having trouble best utilizing fragments in a navigation drawer

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mainactivity.java:**

onNavigationItemSelected method inside this
without Alert Dialog

```
if (mId == R.id.logoutItem){
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
 }
```

with Alert Dialog use

```
if (mId == R.id.logoutItem){
 MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    startActivity(new 
                    Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "clicked Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                .show()
 }
```

Comment: Using the AlertDialog Builder worked! Thanks